# Pass a single data column to a method

Tags: c#

I want to pass a single data row column to a method that does some validation like so:

```
SomeMethod(myDataRow["Col_Name"])
```

I want to do some checking and return a value.  Can't figure out how to pass just that column value for that data row.  I could pass the entire datarow, but I wanted to avoid that.

The idea is to pass the column reference and possibly a type description, sort of like:

```
SomeMethod(dataRowColRef, "ThisColShouldBeAnInt");
```

The some method would validate the value based on whether it's an int, string, whatever and return a "good" value that will make the rest of the program happy.

Thoughts?

Comment: Couldnt you pass a collection ? A list, IEnumerable or other ?

Comment: Why doesn't `SomeMethod(myDataRow["Col_Name"])` not work, assuming signature like `SomeMethod(object colValue)`?

Comment: This is a bit weird. Why are you validating the data type of columns in your database? Don't you have control over your database structure? Usually, data types of columns are inferred before run time, otherwise performance suffers.

Comment: The DataColumn already has a DataType property.  It won't accept the wrong type.  Are you trying to validate the contents of the DataColomn?

Comment: @Diego first off, data in a `DataTable` doesn't have to come from a DataBase.  Second, the `DataRow`'s indexer method returns an `object`.  The coder knows the type, but the compiler doesn't; he just needs to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the value from object to whatever it is before you pass it into the method, i.e.:

```
SomeMethod((int)myDataRow["Col_Name"])
```

If it needs to modify that value it complicates things; you're better off just returning a new value and setting it again if that's what you need, i.e.:

```
myDataRow["Col_Name"] = fixField((int)myDataRow["Col_Name"])
```